# Getting wrong output when finding factorial of number larger than 12

Tags: java

I am trying to solve one [factorial problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL2) provided in codechef in Java. below is my code I tried and getting the results for the numbers up to 12. For 13!, I am getting wrong answer. And I am getting zero output for larger numbers.I am in learning Phase, kindly help me.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner dd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=dd.nextInt();
        long fact[]=new long[a];
        for (int i=0;i<a;i++)
        {
            int b = dd.nextInt();
            int factorial=0,d=0;
            if(b==0) System.out.println(1);
            for(int temp=b-1;temp>1;temp=d-1)
            {
                d=temp;
                b=b*temp;
            }
            fact[i]=b;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<a;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(fact[j]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

13! is larger than max int value and you're computing it on integers.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to long. But my output is exceeding long limit also it seems after 21!. What to do for that

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve? You can try operating on BigDecimal or similar class

Comment: ok, so in theory BigInteger class should be able to handle such numbers